# Control a Google Calendar with a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to be able to update, delete, and add new events from my sheet to the calendar by running the code from the sheet. So far I can add new events and prevent the uploading of duplicate events, but I need the sheet to be able to make amendments and/or delete events on the calendar that were changed/deleted on my sheet.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
function CreateEvent() 
{
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

var calendarId = sheet.getRange("D2").getValue();

var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById ('CalendarID');

var lr = sheet.getLastRow();

var count = sheet.getRange("A9:E"+lr+"").getValues();

for (x=0; x<count.length; x++) {
          var shift = count[x];
      
      var summary = shift[0];
      var startTime = shift[1];
      var endTime = shift[2];
      var guests = shift[3];
      var location = shift[4]; 
  
      var event = {
          'location': location,
          'guests':guests +',',
          'sendInvites': 'True',
}
var events = eventCal.getEvents(startTime, endTime, {search: summary});
if (events.length == 0) {
  eventCal.createEvent(summary, startTime, endTime, event);
}
}
}
}
```

Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!!

Comment: Which kind of information do you want to change? Time? guests? Location? How will you tell the script that you want to delete / modify an event? Do you have columns with checkboxes to indicate that youu want to modify / delete? Or are those requests contiane din a different sheet than the requests to create an event?

Comment: I have a sheet that has the following columns that will act as the source for the calendar: Task, Start Time, End Time, Attendees, Location. If i change any one of them on the sheet, I would like the calendar to update when I run the script.

Comment: In order to verify either the event already exist - it needs to have some constant identifier that does not change. What would be this identifier in your case? Summary? Also startTime and endTime?

Comment: That will be the summary, where I have used the CONCATENATE function and created a unique event ID that combines Task, Start Time, End Time, and Location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To update the details of an already existing event, it's best to use the [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar)

- It allows you to use the Calendar API method [Events: update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update) in Apps Script.
- To [enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) the Advanced Calendar Service Go on `Resources > Advanced Google services`
- Once done, you can modify your code as following to modify already existing events:

```js
function CreateEvent() 
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();  
  var calendarId = sheet.getRange("D2").getValue();  
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);  
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();  
  var count = sheet.getRange("A9:E"+lr).getValues();  
  for (x=0; x<count.length; x++) {
    var shift = count[x];    
    var summary = shift[0];
    var startTime = shift[1];
    var endTime = shift[2];
    var guests = shift[3];
    var location = shift[4];     
    var event = {
      'location': location,
      'guests':guests +',',
      'sendInvites': 'True',
    }       
    //today
    var minTimeRange=new Date();
    //in one year
    var maxTimeRange=new Date();
    maxTimeRange.setDate(minTimeRange.getDate()+365);
    //Given that your start and end time might be modfied, you need to specify a search range where your event is located
    var events = eventCal.getEvents(minTimeRange, maxTimeRange, {search: summary});
    if (events.length == 0) {
      Logger.log("creating event: " + summary);
      eventCal.createEvent(summary, startTime, endTime, event);
    } else{
      Logger.log("modifying: " + summary); 
      var id = events[0].getId().split("@")[0];
       Logger.log("id: " + id); 
      var guestArray = guests.split();
      var attendees =[];
      guestArray.forEach(function(guest){
        attendees.push({email: guest});
        }
      );
      var resource = {
        summary: summary,
        location: location,
        start: {
          dateTime: startTime.toISOString()
        },
        end: {
          dateTime: endTime.toISOString()
        },
        attendees: attendees    
      }
      Calendar.Events.patch(resource, calendarId, id);
    }    
    
  }
}
```

**Keep in mind:**

- Given that your `startTime` and `endTime` might be modified, they are not suitable criteria for defining the timerange for `getEvents` - provide a more generous margin
- When retrieving the `eventId` with calendarApp it will return the `iCalUID`ending with `@google.com` - you need to strip this part to be able to use the `eventId` with the Advanced Calendar Service, see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getid).
- For the Advanced Calendar Service, you need to convert the start and and time to an `ISOString`
- The attendess have been specified as an array of objects in the form `[{email:guest1},{email:gueest2}]`

Comment: This is great, thank you very much. A couple things that this code this isn't allowing me to do in send e-mail invites to the e-mails listed in the "guests" section of the sheet. The other issue is that it doesn't delete events on the calendar that I have deleted on the sheet.

Comment: How would you implement deleting the events that you deleted on the sheet? You might want to llok into [Script properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties) for this.